# How to select last record in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have pretty simple measurement in influxDB and have default time column and two other columns as shown below,

Select * from measurement

gives me this out put.

```
time                            component_id    jkey
2016-09-27T02:49:17.837587671Z      3   "timestamp"
2016-09-27T02:49:17.849447239Z      3   "init_time"
2016-09-27T02:49:17.885999439Z      3   "ae_name"
2016-09-27T02:49:17.893056849Z      3   "init_time"
```

How can i select the last record of this measurement? The record which have maximum time value.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done with `last()`. See the docs for more information: [link](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0//query_language/functions/#last). Or take a look at this example from the docs.

```
SELECT LAST("water_level") FROM "h2o_feet" WHERE "location" = 'santa_monica'
```

This will return the "newest" entry.

Comment: thanks it worked. I was actually using min or max function. but that didn't worked.